# How do I create mock if my trait uses self-type restriction?

Tags: unit-testing, scala, mocking, spray

I'm trying to use cake pattern and mocking. After reading bunch of blog-posts with tons of fashionable terms I can't make it working :(

I'm using Spray and have following http service

```
trait ApiServiceAbstract extends HttpService with SprayJsonSupport {
  this : AppProvider =>
// tons of routes here
}
```

where `AppProvider` is

```
trait AppProvider {
  val api : ApiManager
}
```

For real server I combine it like this

```
class ApiServiceActor extends Actor with ApiServiceAbstract with RealApiManager {
}
```

where `RealApiManager` extends `AppProvider`.

Also `ApiManager` must be mixed in with `DbProvider` which looks like this

```
trait ApiManager {
  this : DbProvider =>
}

trait RealDbProvider extends DbProvider {
  override lazy val dbManager = new DBManager
}
```

In my unit-test I only want to test http portion and have mocked `ApiManager` which simply checks that object passed by the client is correct one.

I cannot do this

```
override lazy val api = mock[ApiManager]
```

because `ApiManager` has to be mixed in with `DbProvider`. How can I fix this ? I see two options right now:

- Switch to mocking library that can instantiate classes with constructors with parameters (e.g. Mockito)
- Add `init(db : DBManager)` method and have `var` in `ApiManager` which is ugly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of my answer because you don't provide all the source code (ApiManager...)

You could create an intermediary trait.

```
trait ApiManagerDefaultMixin extends ApiManager with DbProvider
```

and then

```
val apiManager = new ApiManagerDefaultMixin { 
    override lazy val api = mock[ApiManager]
}
```